# Blender donut color randomisation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLw0HwphXO0

I'm on this video of the tutorial and have got everything else working, but on the shading tab, when I add the object info node, and connect random, like he does at around 10:53, the sprinkles don't change to random colours from black to white. I saw something in the comments saying it had to do with EEVEE, but when I changed to Cycles it just went pink.

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform like workupload

Comment: thanks, file shared. should i share the texture asset for the doughnut too or is that unnecessary

Comment: If it's a tutorial, you are meant to do it as many times as you need to until you get it. There is no clear question here, as you have not described your problem. If you do it "like he does", you will get the result like he does, so that's a useless explanation. You need to find out what you do differently and I don't think anyone here will be able to tell you what you do differently, because only you can know this. I am voting to close the question.

Comment: I guess you forgot to link the material to all sprinkles, haven't you? You can assign one material to multiple objects. The operation *Link Material* does this for all selected objects. The orange selected one is the source & the red ones are the targets. So 1) select the first sprinkle and 2) assign a material. Then 3) select all sprinkles (first one=orange). 4) assign the new material to all of them (CTRL+L > Link Material). Now, you can 5) edit the material in the shader editor and all sprinkles should get a random value between 0=black and 1=white: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBl0r.jpg

Answer (score 1):

First thing, your five particle objects have 3 different materials, so you need to give them the same material, as Blender Guru does: Select them all, at last select the one that you want to make active and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Materials*:

[image]

Now open the *Shader Editor*, create the *Input > Object Info* node and use its *Random* output, it works:

[image]